# Как на консоль вывести симол “ ★ ” (U+2605)

Tags: c#, .net

Необходимо вывести звезду на консоль. 
Делаю вот так

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode;
            Console.Write('\u2605');
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Но выводит просто квадрат. Шрифт в консоли Lucida Console
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а у вас в консоли какая кодировка стоит?

Comment: Кодировку выставите, чтобы была поддержка `Unicode` символов. Например `UTF-8`. `Console.OutputEncoding=Encoding.UTF8;`

Comment: выставил `chcp 65001`. теперь валится с ошибкой

Comment: но ошибку вы не покажете? :)

Comment: @tym32167. Прошу прощения по поводу ошибки. Выставил `Console.OutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8` , но все по прежнему. Может необходимо шрифт добавить в консоль который будет поддерживать этот символ?

Comment: [How to write Unicode characters to the console?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5750227/312041)

Comment: Самое правильное решение - не используйте консоль для работы с юникодом. Сделайте графическое приложение (WinForms, WPF, Xamarin, etc)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, да что вы говорите, а ему нужно консоль. представьте себе. Вопрос про консоль, а не граф приложения.

Comment: Я делал тестовое задание и там необходимо было вывести на консоль заполненные звезды или пустые . Использовал другие символы , но все же хотелось понять как вывести на консоль эти звёзды

Comment: @And - Я оставил _комментарий_, а не _ответ_. Не кипятитесь.

Comment: По идее, что-то типа такого должно сработать: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38533903/set-c-sharp-console-application-to-unicode-output. Но я так понимаю, что главная проблема в том, что в Lucida Console нет этих символов-звёздочек.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, в C# консоль отлично работает с юникодом по умолчанию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Установил шрифт для командной строки [DejaVu Sans Mono](https://www.fontspace.com/category/monospace,unicode)

[вот](https://github.com/aksakalli/gtop/wiki/Windows-Command-Prompt-Font-Support) таким способом

и получил результат

[image]

Comment: А если просто Consolas выбрать?

Comment: @Qwertiy На Consolas у меня  знаки вопросов

Comment: @Qwertiy а разве консольный line-height не от шрифта зависит?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/97717/discussion-between-qwertiy-and-pavel-mayorov).